# SEO - how can a crawler be asked to wait while data loads before crawling?

Tags: angularjs, seo, firebase, angular-ui-router

I'm using a mvvc framework (Angular) and having some trouble getting the site data indexed. All the static data is crawled fine but dynamic data from a cloud db is missed.

Is there any way to politely ask a crawler to wait a few hundred ms before going at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to tell a spider to wait. This would be counter-productive since their job is to index data as quickly as possible and each wait would accumulate into days/weeks/months of delays. (Note that Google has explored some javascript rendering, but that won't help with XHR content).

The correct answer is to explore [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/). The gist of this approach is that you utilize a tool like prerender.io during your deploy process to pre-render dynamic content. Then you list that content in your sitemap and either utilize the `_escaped_fragment_` rewrites at your server or the meta tag as explained here (from Getting Started):

> In order to make pages without hash fragments crawlable, you include a special meta tag in the head of the HTML of your page. The meta tag takes the following form:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

In both cases, you still have to pre-render dynamic content to cached HTML pages and make those available to the search engine when it requests content from your server.

Comment: thanks. Followed your advice and installed prerender.io on a node.js server. Prerender.io has cached the pages appropriately but GWT fetch and render is still pulling no data. Is there another step to take?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to put noindex, nofollow that time.

after load data fully, you can remove that tags.

Comment: but i do want the page to be crawled and indexed - only AFTER the data loads from a remote source.

Comment: This is extremely bad advice. When the google crawler detects a noindex or nofollow property during their first crawl wave, they will most likely ignore it during their 2nd crawl wave, even if it now doesn't have those properties.